# Product page fails to render

Tags: upgrade, composer, product-page, magento2.3.2

When you click on a product page, it only shows a one image.  Looking at the stack trace, it looks like there is some PHP error.  I think when I patched to 2.3.2, maybe something didn't updated?  How do I recover?

eg. click the product, then it is only the product image showing afterwards.
[image]

```
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
<img
alt="main product photo"
class="gallery-placeholder__image"
src="https://steamspeed.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/85991805028918d3c76d0ac026e0a79d/j/b/jb-rebuild_1000x1000.png"
/>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
"[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
"mage/gallery/gallery": {
"mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
"magnifierOpts": {"fullscreenzoom":"5","top":"","left":"","width":"","height":"","eventType":"hover","enabled":false},
"data": [{"thumb":"https:\/\/steamspeed.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/155e93c92386e3c82347ea16620ccbd3\/j\/b\/jb-rebuild_1000x1000.png","img":"https:\/\/steamspeed.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/85991805028918d3c76d0ac026e0a79d\/j\/b\/jb-rebuild_1000x1000.png","full":"https:\/\/steamspeed.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/8626c40ec5098cb7aa441a37fc63fc11\/j\/b\/jb-rebuild_1000x1000.png","caption":"SteamSpeed Journal Bearing Rebuild Kit for MHI Compatible CHRA","position":"1","isMain":true,"type":"image","videoUrl":null}],
"options": <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getOptionsJson() on null in /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml:48
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php-&gt;render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery/Interceptor.php(505): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template-&gt;fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor-&gt;fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Elemen in <b>/var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
```

Comment: Have you customized the catalog_product_view. xml under the app folder. Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 2):

Magento changed up that block declaration in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml as of 2.3.2.  The related change is...

**pre-2.3.2**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
```

---

**2.3.2**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
        <argument name="imageHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

You likely have an extension or your theme customizing this layout and need to make sure that the new arguments are being passed in like noted above.